# How can I deduce the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(y)e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t} } dy$ without actually evaluating it?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

How can I deduce that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(y)\,e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t} } dy = e^{-t} \sin(x) 
$$
without actually evaluating the definite integral?

Comment: Does the equation hold for ALL $x, t$ or SOME $x, t$? Also, you have not specified to what do $x, t$ refer?

Comment: i suppose it's for all x and t and x and t are the variables in the integral no the LHS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume the following result:

> The solution to the [Heat Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)
>
> $$\frac{df}{dt} = \nabla^2f$$
>
> with initial condition $f(x,0) = g(x)$ can be written
>
> $$f(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}g(y) dy$$

Now by inserting

$$f(x,t) = e^{-t}\sin(x)$$

into the Heat Equation we find that it does satisfy it with the initial condition $f(x,0) = \sin(x)$. From the result above it therefore follows that

$$e^{-t}\sin(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}\sin(y) dy$$

Comment: thanks alot! i think this is what i'm looking for...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** By the change of variable $\displaystyle u=\frac{y-x}{2\sqrt{t}}$, you easily get

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(y)\,e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t} } dy \\\\ &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(2\sqrt{t}\: u+x)\,e^{-u^2 } du \\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos x\sin(2\sqrt{t}u)\,e^{-u^2 } du+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin x\cos(2\sqrt{t}u)\,e^{-u^2 } du \\\\
&=0+\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\pi} }\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(2\sqrt{t}\:u)\,e^{-u^2 } du  \\\\
&= \sin x \:e^{-t} 
\end{align}
$$ where we have just used the parity of one integrand and the classic gaussian evaluation
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(a\:u)\,e^{-u^2 } du=\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{-a^2/4}.
$$